# How to disable the scrollview in LongListSelector in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, longlistselector

I want to disable the scrollview in LongListSelector.

I tried like this:

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector x:Name="List_Contacts" 
                                      IsFlatList= "False"
                                      DisplayAllGroups="False"
                                      Margin="0,0,0,100" 
                                      Width="480" 
                                      Background="Transparent" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ResultList}"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" 
                                      GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupItemHeaderTemplate}"
                                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                      Tap="List_Contacts_Tap"/>
```

But here the scrolling not disabled.

I found one solution from stack overflow

```
<Style x:Key="LongListSelectorWithNoScrollBarStyle" TargetType="toolkit:LongListSelector">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ViewportControl x:Name="ViewportControl" 
                                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

But here i am getting error

**The type 'ViewportControl' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.**

I have include the namespace into the xaml also.

**xmlns:ViewportControl="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows"**

But still now i am getting the `'ViewportControl' was not found` error.

Please help me to disable the scroll in LLS.

[image: Requirment]

Here All the elements are scroll able.. LLS will have N number of items. If I scroll the LLS to top  the above stack panel also should scroll to top.

Comment: why do you want to disable the scroll ? cant you use IsHitTestVisible Property ?

Comment: @Pradeep.. I want to write click event also. So that I can not use this IsHitTestVisible.. My requirement is like that. That's why I am asking like this..

Comment: Explain why you want to disable the scroll ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable scroll by setting the height of LongListSelector(LLS) more than the height of all your Items. You can set a maximum height to your LLS to avoid scrolling.

Having a LLS inside a ScrollViewer is not a good practice, both the scrolls will fight for their input events and result will not be as expected.

Also, to be more focused about your issue, You can add your StackPanels to the `ListHeader` of LLS, so that the StackPanels will also scroll along with your Items when you scroll your LLS.

A Sample structure to make use of `ListHeader` of LLS is,

```
  <phone:LongListSelector>
    <phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Panel1"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Panel2"></StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>
  </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: I can get the LLS items at run time. So I don't know the exact height of LLS.

Comment: Are you Grouping your items using AlphaKeyGroup ? Do you have nested LLS ?

Comment: what do you mean by "Here all the items are scrollable"

Comment: Yes I am using AlphaKeyGroup. All the items are scrollable mean i Put all the items(Stack panel 1, Stack panel 2, LLS) in to ScrollViewer.

Comment: Thats the problem, You should not put your LLS inside Scrollviewer. You have add those to the ListHeader of LLS so that they will be added as first element to your LLS and scrolls up when you scroll the LLS. Hope this helps !!

Comment: Oh.. Thanks.. Can you provide me a simple example for, How to add that two stack panel in to the ListHeader of LLS??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68059/discussion-between-pradeep-aj-and-vijay).